# Forego vs. Forbear vs. Forsake

Tags: synonyms

What is the difference, if any, among forego, forbear, and forsake?

In the thesaurus, 
1. forsake is listed in the entry for synonyms of forego, but forbear is not listed in forego.
2. neither forego nor forbear is listed in the entry for forsake.
3. neither forego nor forsake is listed in the entry for forbear.

Please help me clarify the relationship and differences between these three words.

Thank you,
Kevin C.

Comment: You can't just say "the thesaurus"... there are lots of them!

Comment: Note that the normal spelling of _forgo_ in the sense of "do without [something]" is without an _e_. In the sense of of "go before" the usual spelling is _forego_.

Answer (score 1):

"**Forgo**" and "**forbear**" both have the meaning of giving something up:

> As tempting as the chocolate cake is, I will  have to **forgo** dessert
>   tonight.

Or more [philosophically](https://books.google.com/books?id=vQ6tAAAAQBAJ&pg=PR183&lpg=PR183&dq=%22bear%20and%20forbear%22%20epictetus&source=bl&ots=t8Jyd0Jt23&sig=wBhCRu_UNyfkpI4AAXcc2vTz81M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwADgKahUKEwipto-ige7GAhULGT4KHZbkBMs#v=onepage&q=%22bear%20and%20forbear%22%20epictetus&f=false)

> Favorinus tells us how Epectetus would also say that there were two
>   faults far graver and fouler than any others -- inability to bear and
>   inability to **forbear**, when we neither patiently bear the blows
>   that must be borne, nor abstain from the things and the pleasures we
>   ought to abstain from.

But "forbear" often has the connotation of demonstrating patience in abstaining from a favored action, especially when provoked.  Shakespeare has Henry VI say in the play of the same name, part 2:

> **Forbear** to judge, for we are sinners all.

"**Forsake**" means to abandon. Matthew 27:45–46 quotes Jesus on the cross

> “My God, my God, why have You **forsaken** me?

Answer (score 0):

To what I can understand from the [Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com), I came up with below mentioned solution. 
**Forego** means to go before / to take a lead.

> I was almost ready to **forego** the best presentation of the year

**Forbear** means to step back.

> I cannot **forbear** to note what a splendid evening we had

**Forsake** means to give up.

> I refuse to **forsake** any opportunity for career growth

Definitively, **forgo** means similar to **forbear**, but **forgo** is quite different from **forego**.

Answer (score -1):

All three verbs are very old and a bit rare. To forsake means to abandon or to give up. to forbear and to forgo are similar and mean to renounce. Any online dictionary would answer your question.